# Как поменять видеокарту по умолчанию в ubuntu на nvidia?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

Команда выводит список видеокарт:

```
Код: [Выделить]
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'       
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 825d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все правильно, по умолчанию, всегда, для нетребовательных задач (обычный софт, работа ОС, рабочий стол) должна использоваться интегрированная видеокарта. А уже для требовательных задач, дискретная (Игры). Иначе, дискретная начнет быстро изнашиваться.

Comment: @Руслан где можно подробнее почитать про износ, его причины и сроки? Использую в своём ноутбуке только дискретную в течение четырёх лет — проблем пока не наблюдается

Comment: То есть ubuntu сама выставляет встроенную видеокарту и не даст переключиться на дискретную?

Comment: Первый же ответ в гугле - https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

Comment: Да. Это читал. Там как раз и говорят что переключить карту нужно через 
nvidia-settings. 
Когда он запускается то выглядит как на скриншоте. Там ничего выбрать нельзя.

Comment: Если выглядит как на скриншоте, значит на выбор 2е карты, верно? Или карты 2е, но они серые? Уточните

Comment: Да 2 видеокарты. Их можно переключать, но настройки справа не отображаются. Кликаю по PRIME profiles и ничего не происходит.

Comment: Более простой способ, это отключить ненужную GPU в BIOS и всё. Проблем нет, конфликтов нет, всё летает, ну и т.д. Драйвер рекомендую 390-й, так как он уже стабильный, остальные ещё в нестабильных находятся, могут возникнуть проблемы (ну могут и не возникнуть, тут на свой страх и риск)

Comment: Либо отключать карту, либо попробовать еще и сделать все по новой. Т.е. удалить драйвер нвидиа, и установить заново. Но только из консоли

Comment: @DenisE при двух GPU всё равно неизбежны конфликты, рано или поздно, лучше отключить ненужную, ИМХО. Я это проехал с тремя дистрибутивами (Ubuntu, Debian и Manjaro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в secure boot.

Чтобы установить nvidia драйвер на системе где используется secure boot, нужно предпринять следующие действия:

1. Зайти в Программы и обновления -> Дополнительные драйверы
2. Выбрать версию драйвера [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Нажать кнопку применить изменения.
4. В момент установки драйвера вылезет окно secure boot где нужно будет придумать пароль.
5. После окончания установки, нужно перезагрузить компьютер.
6. Появится окно secure boot в котором нужно выбрать пункт 2 enroll mok. Далее ввести пароль и продолжить загрузку в обычном режиме.
7. После окончанию загрузки должен отобразиться корректный драйвер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь **Fedora 35**. Тут стоит **GNOME 41.1**.
Для того чтобы использовать только дискретку, нужно накатить актуальную версию драйверов и добавить в чёрный список драйвер от встройки. Я пользуюсь vim, но можно любым другим редактором, в терменале пишем:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Если файл новый, бекап делать не нужно,а так рекомендую. Теперь последней строчкой добавь:

```
blacklist i915
```

После этого перезапусти ноутбук и вместо встройки будет пахать дискретка. На ноутбуках с процессорами от красных я не тестил.

Answer (score 0):

cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf.bak
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf закоментить
https://zalinux.ru/?p=3461

Comment: А при чём тут amdgpu, если в упомянутой конфигурации компьютера нет вообще никаких намёков на AMD?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/880439)